# Binding data to a flowdocument

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, flowdocument

I'm working with .NET 4.5 and I like bind data to a flowdocument. But it makes some problems.

The first case is when I load the document via xaml:

```
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="{Binding FirstName, FallbackValue='error on binding'}" />
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

When I load it and asign the DataContext like

```
document = ... as FlowDocument;
document.DataContext = MyObject;
```

The result is, that the FallbackValue of the binding definition is shown (means the value 'error on binding' is shown). That says to me, that something happens with databinding, but not what I wanted (the value of 'FirstName' property).

The second case is when I create the document via code:

```
var inline = new Run();
inline.DataContext = SelectedPerson;

var binding = new Binding("FirstName");
binding.FallbackValue = "an error occurred";

inline.SetBinding(Run.TextProperty, binding);

var block = new Paragraph(inline);
document = new FlowDocument(block);
```

That works! But when I set the DataContext after I've set the binding it didn't. Then the value 'error on binding' is shown once again.

In the end I would love to load the document via a xaml file include all binding definitions, set the DataContext (without explicit knowing which bindings are inside). It seems to be very close to this but I can't take the final step.

Does anybody have an idea how to take this?

Best regards,
Torsten

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but does `SelectedPerson` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?